# JSF xhtml page not found

Tags: spring-boot, jsf-2.2

I've been trying to follow various articles on setting up my first JSF application and can't get my first xhtml page to be found.  I keep getting the error "This application has no explicit mapping for /error, so you are seeing this as a fallback" in the browser.

In the browser, I type http://localhost:8080/modelSimulation.xhtml to get this error, and in the console, I see:
... :GET "/modelSimulation.xhtml", parameters={} 
... :No mapping for GET /modelSimulation.xhtml

My spring boot application has added the various things required to setup JSF with spring boot, but clearly I'm missing something to be able to view my modelSimulation.xhtml page.  What am I missing? Thanks!

I also tried http://localhost:8080 but get corresponding no mapping error too.

---

**src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/modelSimulation.xhtml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
        "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:h="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/html"
      xmlns:ui="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/facelets" xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">
<ui:composition template="layout.xhtml">
    <ui:define name="content">
        <h:form id="mainForm">
            <p:panel header="Details">
                <h:panelGrid columns="1">
                    <p:outputLabel for="symbol" value="Symbol: " />
                    <p:inputText id="symbol" value="#{tradingModelSimulationController.symbol}" />
                    <p:outputLabel for="ranking" value="ranking: " />
                    <p:inputNumber id="ranking" value="#{tradingModelSimulationController.ranking}" />
                    <h:commandButton value="apply" action="#{tradingModelSimulationController.apply}" />
                </h:panelGrid>
            </p:panel>
        </h:form>
    </ui:define>
</ui:composition>
</html>
```

---

**src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/web.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee" version="3.1">
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>*.jsf</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>
    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.request.RequestContextListener</listener-class>
    </listener>
</web-app>
```

---

I added the 2 required beans to the **SpringBootApplication class**:

```
@Bean
public ServletRegistrationBean servletRegistrationBean() {
    FacesServlet servlet = new FacesServlet();
    return new ServletRegistrationBean(servlet, "*.jsf");
}
@Bean
public FilterRegistrationBean rewriteFilter() {
    FilterRegistrationBean rwFilter = new FilterRegistrationBean(new RewriteFilter());
    rwFilter.setDispatcherTypes(EnumSet.of(DispatcherType.FORWARD, DispatcherType.REQUEST,
            DispatcherType.ASYNC, DispatcherType.ERROR));
    rwFilter.addUrlPatterns("/*");
    return rwFilter;
}
```

---

Here's the backing bean  **(I don't understand the @Join...)**

```
@Scope(value = "session")
@Component(value = "tradingModelSimulationController")
@ELBeanName(value = "tradingModelSimulationController")
@Join(path = "/modelSimulation", to = "/modelSimulation.jsf")
public class TradingModelSimulationController {

    ModelSimulation modelSimulation = new ModelSimulation();

    String symbol;
    int ranking;

    public void apply() {

        System.out.println("Applied: " + modelSimulation.toString());

        RequestContext.getCurrentInstance()
            .execute("handleMsg('applied!');");
    }

    public ModelSimulation getModelSimulation() {
        return modelSimulation;
    }

    public String getSymbol() {
        return symbol;
    }

    public void setSymbol(String symbol) {
        this.symbol = symbol;
    }

    public int getRanking() {
        return ranking;
    }

    public void setRanking(int ranking) {
        this.ranking = ranking;
    }
}
```

Comment: Why do you type `http://localhost:8080/modelSimulation.xhtml`  when you have `<url-pattern>*.jsf</url-pattern>` AND `return new ServletRegistrationBean(servlet, "*.jsf");` (which seems duplicateion). Please start with a good SpringBoot/JSF tutorial (or use joinfaces which afaik, does all this for you)

Comment: I've been following this one https://dzone.com/articles/developing-jsf-applications-with-spring-boot.  I'm not sure which url to hit. I'll try to find another article and cross-reference what I missed.

Comment: Try `http://localhost:8080/modelSimulation.jsf` (or change the extension in the config to `.xhtml`. And again, try joinfaces. Makes all this way easier (Nowadays Spring makes a lot of things harder instead of easier).

Comment: I tried the url with the jsf exception - no luck.  I changed the servlet registration bean to "*.xhtml" and hit the page with .xhtml extension and got this error:  2019-01-06 12:57:38.643 ERROR 13808 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/].[facesServlet]         : Servlet.service() for servlet [facesServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [javax/servlet/jsp/jstl/core/Config] with root cause

java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/servlet/jsp/jstl/core/Config
 at JspViewDeclarationLanguage.buildView. (called by RenderResponseExecutor.execute(...)

Comment: joinfaces sounds interesting. i'll give it a try.  thanks!